# Homebrew claims cairo depends on Python

Tags: homebrew, dependency-management

When uninstalling the python@3.9 package, Homebrew complains that the *cairo* package depends on it. This is unlikely to be true:

```
brew uses python@3.9
```

lists several packages but not *cairo*, and

```
brew deps --tree cairo
```

shows a tree without any python@*.* in it. On the other hand,

```
brew uses --installed python@3.9
```

does list the *cairo* package, and commands like `brew missing` and `brew doctor` create a warning about the missing dependency *python@3.9*.

I don't know whether the *cairo* package (see its formula [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/cairo.rb)) somehow depends on *python@3.9*, but I guess it does not, and the behavior is weird. What's going on and how can it be fixed?

Comment: My best guess is maybe your local clone of homebrew/core is outdated. `brew update` and `brew upgrade` might help if this is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found **what causes the problem**, inspired by [a comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4737#issuecomment-414964658) on an old issue on Homebrew's Github repository:

> `brew uses --installed` uses the dependency resolution information from your installed formulae whereas `brew uses` alone does not.

Indeed, whereas [the formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/cairo.rb) doesn't contain a dependency on *python@3.9*, the installed package does: on my system, the file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json has a key `runtime_dependencies` that includes this element:

```json
{
   "full_name": "python@3.9",
   "version": "3.9.9",
   "declared_directly": false
}
```

In [a further comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4737#issuecomment-415025147), the developer explains:

> When built from source some things pick up dependencies opportunistically i.e. they link against stuff without us trying to make them do so. The other thing where this kicks in is if you've built a formula with a particular, non-default option. We now store these links in the formula itself and use it for certain commands so you get a result that's correct for your system (i.e. `brew uses --installed` doesn't miss results that will break things if uninstalled).

This may not be a complete explanation (I'm pretty sure I installed cairo from a binary 'bottle' without any non-standard options), but it does suggest the general area where the issue may have arisen.

The next thing to find out is **how to resolve the issue**. I don't know whether there's an official workaround, but the options seem to be

1. Manually remove that part from INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
2. Uninstall the *cairo* package while suppressing warnings and removal of dependent packages, and then reinstall it.

I chose 1. and it seems (so far) to work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a newer issue:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/13717

tldr;

```
brew reinstall cairo
brew rm python@3.9
```